# Hibernate Query Like Issue

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, sql-like

I am currently creating a user defined search, my problem is that when it comes to normal sql( I run it in my database) it returns a result, but when it comes to HQL it does not return any result.

example. I made this query in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_PROFILES WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%somevalue existinDb%';
```

this returns a value however with HQL Query Object

```
  String someValue = "somevalue existinDb"
    String temp_name = "%" +someValue + "%";
            System.out.println(temp_name);
            Query query =  sess().createQuery(
                    "from UserProfile where firstName  LIKE :temp_name").setParameter("temp_name",temp_name);
```

But However the HQL QUery Object does not render the same result as the SQL Query. Why is it like that?

Comment: Try adding single quotes to the beginning and end of temp_name  which you are forming

Comment: @Renjith tried it still did not work.

Comment: is there exception? how does your `somevalue existinDb` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

sess().createQuery(
"from UserProfile where firstName  LIKE :temp_name").setParameter("temp_name",'%' + someValue + '%');

And a much simpler method:
String someValue = "somevalue existinDb"
String temp_name = "%" +someValue + "%";
Query query = session.createQuery(“from UserProfile where firstName LIKE ?” );
query.setString(0, temp_name);

Comment: wouldn't make my Query prone to SQL injection

Comment: I wont understand that.How it will cause SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

```
String temp_name = "%'" +someValue + "'%";
```

will work for you. I had the same problem before. If it is not working you should play around with the `%`s. I think that putting a `%` in the front of the parameter will not work.

The `%` sign can be used to define wildcards (missing letters in the pattern) both before and after the pattern. So if you put `%` in the front of the string you are looking for some missing string before `someValue`.

Comment: So do you suggest I do not put any % ? I did try putting the % at the end but still no result

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) for such a query: is more efficient and will match results much better, resulting in a more user friendly application.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `"/%"` instead of `"%"`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you elaborate on why this answer is correct? Even if it doesn't seem needed to you, an explanation may be very helpful to the OP or future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I typed wrongly, it must be "\%". "%" is a special character and you must use "\%" to make hibernate understands that you want to add "%" in your query.